# NodeJS - How to insert script node to the beginning of an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to use `NodeJS` to modify an `HTML` file in order to append a script tag to the beginning of the `HTML` so that it executes before all other scripts.

My current code looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const parse = require('node-html-parser').parse;

fs.readFile('test.html', 'utf8', (err,html)=>{
   if(err){
      throw err;
   }

   const root = parse(html);

   const head = root.querySelector('head');
   if (head !== null) {
      head.insertBefore( '<script src = "test.js"></script>', head.firstChild);
      fs.writeFile('test.html', root.toString(), function (err) {
           if (err) return console.log(err);
      });
   }
 });
```

But `insertBefore` is throwing an exception. How can I correct this?

Comment: Please post the error you are getting. I don't see any `insertBefore` method in the API reference for that library, and I wouldn't necessarily expect it to support all DOM methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insertBefore` takes a *node* as its first argument; you're passing it a string. Insert the script with `innerHTML` instead:

```
head.innerHTML = '<script src = "test.js"></script>' + head.innerHTML;
```

`insertAdjacentHTML` could be used too.

Comment: ```document``` is not defined. When I use ```root```, I get ```root.createElement is not a function```

Comment: Oh, of course. You can prepend the `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: Or you can use `parse()` to create the `<script>` (probably)